# Implementation of DBSCAN in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, clustering, geospatial

I've recently just finished my implementation of a DBSCAN in C++ for a machine learning framework. I've tried to follow the pseudocode implementation on Wikipedia as best I could. I also found some example implementations on Github to help as well. So far, this is what my code looks like. I was wondering if my implementation looks similar to the pseudocode and if their was anything I could add in terms of correctness or even speed.

```
std::vector<uint32_t> DBSCAN::regionQuery(uint32_t p)
{
   Metrics metrics;
   MetricCoordinates _mc;
   uint32_t coordinates_size = coordinates[0]->lat_pts.size();
   if (cluster_weights.dist_metric == "haversine"){
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < coordinates_size; i++){
         _mc.lat_1 = coordinates[0]->lat_pts[i];
         _mc.lat_2 = coordinates[0]->lat_pts[p];
         _mc.long_1 = coordinates[0]->long_pts[i];
         _mc.long_2 = coordinates[0]->long_pts[p];
         if (metrics.haversineDistanceMetric(_mc) <= cluster_weights.eps){
            rq_pts.push_back(i);
         }
      }
   } else if (cluster_weights.dist_metric == "euclidean"){
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < coordinates_size; i++){
         _mc.lat_1 = coordinates[0]->lat_pts[i];
         _mc.lat_2 = coordinates[0]->lat_pts[p];
         _mc.long_1 = coordinates[0]->long_pts[i];
         _mc.long_2 = coordinates[0]->long_pts[p];
         if (metrics.euclideanDistanceMetric(_mc) <= cluster_weights.eps){
            rq_pts.push_back(i);
         }
      }
   }
   // all points within the eps neighborhood
   return rq_pts;
}

void DBSCAN::expandCluster(uint32_t p, std::vector<uint32_t>* ec_neighbor_pts, int32_t* n_clusters)
{
   cluster_pts.push_back(std::vector<int32_t>());
   cluster_pts[*n_clusters].push_back(p);
   uint32_t ec_neighbors_size = ec_neighbor_pts->size();
   assert(ec_neighbors_size != 0);
   for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ec_neighbors_size; i++){
      if (!visited_pts[ec_neighbor_pts->at(i)]){
         // mark point p as visited
         visited_pts[ec_neighbor_pts->at(i)] = true;
         std::vector<uint32_t> ec_neighbor_pts_ = regionQuery(ec_neighbor_pts->at(i));
         if (ec_neighbor_pts_.size() >= cluster_weights.min_pts){
            ec_neighbor_pts->insert(ec_neighbor_pts->end(), ec_neighbor_pts_.begin(), ec_neighbor_pts_.end());
         }
         // mark point p as clustered
         clustered_pts[ec_neighbor_pts->at(i)] = true;
         // add any other points that haven't been clustered
         if (clustered_pts[ec_neighbor_pts->at(i)]){
            cluster_pts[*n_clusters].push_back(ec_neighbor_pts->at(i));
         }
      }
   }
}

void DBSCAN::performClusterSearch()
{
   uint32_t coordinates_size = coordinates[0]->lat_pts.size();
   for (uint32_t i = 0; i < coordinates_size; i++){
      if (visited_pts[i]) {
         continue;
      } else {
         // mark point p as visited
         visited_pts[i] = true;
         std::vector<uint32_t> rq_neighbor_pts = regionQuery(i);
         if (rq_neighbor_pts.size() < cluster_weights.min_pts){
            noise_pts_.push_back(rq_neighbor_pts[i]);
         } else {
            n_clusters_++;
            // mark point p as clustered
            clustered_pts[i] = true;
            expandCluster(i, &rq_neighbor_pts, &n_clusters_);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Similarity to the pseudocode

> I've tried to follow the pseudocode implementation on Wikipedia as best I could. [...] I was wondering if my implementation looks similar to the pseudocode

There are obvious differences. You could have written your functions to be much closer to the pseudocode, both the order of the operations themselves, the names of functions and variables, and even the arguments to the functions. Your implementation is also specificly made to work with the type of elements of the member variable `coordinates`. But you can make a generic version of the DBSCAN algorithm in C++ by using templates:

```
template<typename Container, typename DistFunc>
void DBSCAN(const Container& DB,
            DistFunc distFunc,
            float eps,
            std::size_t minPts)
{
    std::size_t C = 0;

    for (auto& point: DB) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course, it's going to be a bit harder to write fully generic code. Also, the pseudocode on Wikipedia just handwaves what `label()` is and how it is returned. If you know your container is a `std::vector`, then you can store the set of neighbors in a `std::vector` of indices, or even a `std::vector<bool>` of the same length as the number of points. For other container types you might need to store iterators or references.

Note that you can also choose to make only some parts of your code more generic. Consider the distance metric: you had to write the loop twice in `regionQuery()`, and it only supports two distance metrics. If you want to add another distance metric, you also have to add another `else if` to `regionQuery()` and increase the amount of code duplication. Passing a [`std::function<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) that holds the distance metric function to `regionQuery()` would simplify the code significantly.

## Pass by reference where appropriate

Instead of using pointers, consider passing by reference. This avoids having to dereference explicitly.

In the case of `n_clusters` you should pass it by value to `expandCluster()`, as it will not change during that function call.

## Use `[]` instead of `at()`

You are using both `[]` and `at()` to access elements of vectors, however `at()` does a range check and will throw an exception if the index is out of range. This adds a little bit of overhead, and is unnecessary if you already know the index is in range.

I suspect you did this because you are passing some vectors using pointers, and then it looks cleaner than writing either of these:

```
(*ec_neighor_pts)[i];
ec_neighbor_pts->operator[](i);
```

But if you pass by reference, that issue will go away.

## Naming things

Why does `_mc` have an underscore at the start? You don't do this for other variables. I would just write `mc` instead. There are also certain [restrictions on when you can use underscores in identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Your use is fine, but I would adhere to these simpler rules that are easier to remember: never use a leading underscore, and never use double underscores.

In `expandCluster()` you have a function parameter `ec_neighbor_pts` and a local variable `ec_neighbor_pts_`. This is very confusing, and makes the code hard to understand. I suggest you rename `ec_neighbor_pts_` to something that is clearly distinct.

## Use `std::size_t` for sizes, counts and indices

While it might not sound likely to happen, consider that on 64-bit systems, a `std::vector` might hold more than \$2^{32}\$ elements. Therefore, `uint32_t` will be too small to hold an index into such a large vector. The proper type to use that is guaranteed to be able to hold any index into an array that fits in memory is [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

## Performance

The main problem with the algorithm you implemented is that `RangeQuery()` does a linear scan through the list of all points. Since it is called at least once for every point, this means your algorithm has time complexity \$O(N^2)\$, where \$N\$ is the number of points. For small sets of points this is fine, but it quickly becomes slower and slower.

You can avoid this by using a datastructure that makes searching for points close to a given point faster. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors) for a possible solution.

Comment: I've implemented this by myself in my machine learning 101 class, I was curious why the original author didn't use Union-Find

Comment: @frozenca Union-Find the operation or the data structure? If minPts = 2 then DBSCAN becomes the disjoint set problem, but otherwise I don't see how it would help.